# RequestMapping Unable to populate Entity class where fields within EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have the following Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reporteddevicedata", schema="schemaName")
public class MobileDeviceData {

    @EmbeddedId 
    MobileDeviceDataId mobileDeviceDataId;

    @Column(name="activitydetecteddate")
    private ZonedDateTime activityDetectedDate;

    public void setFlagId(int flagId) {
        mobileDeviceDataId.setFlagId(flagId);
    }

    ......
}

@Embeddable
class MobileDeviceDataId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="clientid")
    private int clientId;

    @Column(name="flagid")
    private int flagId;
}
```

My `Controller` code looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mobile/device", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Object> flagDevice (@RequestBody List<MobileDeviceData> deviceInfoList) {
    // code here
}
```

Originally I had my `Entity` class with just one primary key `@ID` on the `clientId` and it worked great. I would make a REST call and it would populate the MobileDeviceData class as expected. Then I switched to a composite ID using the `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddableId` annotation and now the `@RequestMapping` is unable to populate the `flagId` parameter. Now when I make a REST call I get a null pointer exception for `mobileDeviceDataId`, thus its unable to update that field when it gets called and Throws a null pointer exception.

So my question is, how do I get an instance of the `@Embeddable` class? Can I just create one with `new`? I'm not sure of the implications of this since Spring may be expecting to make that value itself? What is the "normal" way this field would get updated via `RequestMapping`?

Comment: Where does your error show? Does it happen while you try to put data? Add some example requestbody that you send then i might help you figure it out

Comment: @OskarDajnowicz - I've updated the question. Setting the Spring logs to debug showed me what the error was. So now I would just like to know expected way or "best practice" on how to update the fields within the Embeddable class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should avoid embedded id's, it just makes all things harder

surrogate primary keys are just easier to use, when you have a foreign key on a table with multi-column primary key it makes it much more complicated to deal with

now you faced these problems by yourself but according to your question

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mobile/device", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Object> flagDevice (@RequestBody List<MobileDeviceData> deviceInfoList) {
    for(MobileDeviceData mobileDeviceData : deviceInfoList){
        int clientId = mobileDeviceData.getMobileDeviceDataId().getClientId();
        int flagId = mobileDeviceData.getMobileDeviceDataId().getFlagId();
        MobileDeviceData foundMobileDeviceData = mobileDeviceDataService.findByClientIdAndFlagId(clientId, flagId);
        if(foundMovileDeviceData == null){
            mobileDeviceDataService.save(mobileDeviceData);
        }else {
            //update foundMobileDeviceData with mobileDeviceData  fields
            mobileDeviceDataService.save(foundMobileDeviceData);
        }
    }
}
```

else if you want to update just flag id

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mobile/device", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Object> flagDevice (@RequestBody List<MobileDeviceData> deviceInfoList) {
    for(MobileDeviceData mobileDeviceData : deviceInfoList){
        int clientId = mobileDeviceData.getMobileDeviceDataId().getClientId();
        MobileDeviceData foundMobileDeviceData = mobileDeviceDataService.findByClientId(clientId);
        if(foundMovileDeviceData == null){
            mobileDeviceDataService.save(mobileDeviceData);
        }else {
            //update foundMobileDeviceData with mobileDeviceData 
            int flagId  = foundMobileDeviceData.getMobileDeviceDataId().getFlagId();
            MobileDeviceDataId mobileDeviceDataId = foundMobileDeviceData.getMobileDeviceDataId();
            mobileDeviceDataId.setFlagId(mobileDeviceData)

            mobileDeviceDataService.save(foundMobileDeviceData);
        }
    }
}
```

Next if you want to find something by client id just create a JPA Query like

```
"from MobileDeviceData WHERE mobileDeviceDataId.clientId = :clientId"
```

or native sql

```
"SELECT * FROM reporteddevicedata WHERE client_id = :someParam"
```

EXAMPLE JSON Request

```
[ {
  "mobileDeviceDataId" : {
    "clientId" : 0,
    "flagId" : 0
  },
  "activityDetectedDate" : null
}, {
  "mobileDeviceDataId" : {
    "clientId" : 1,
    "flagId" : 1
  },
  "activityDetectedDate" : null
}, {
  "mobileDeviceDataId" : {
    "clientId" : 2,
    "flagId" : 2
  },
  "activityDetectedDate" : null
} ]
```

uglified ready to copy/paste version :

```
[{"mobileDeviceDataId":{"clientId":0,"flagId":3},"activityDetectedDate":null},{"mobileDeviceDataId":{"clientId":1,"flagId":1},"activityDetectedDate":null},{"mobileDeviceDataId":{"clientId":2,"flagId":2},"activityDetectedDate":null}]
```

Additionaly there should be some validation added on your MobileData object to avoid nullpointers when an invalid json request is send (with no mobileDeviceDataId present)

**Finally answering the question:**

Its not considered a good practice to use database model as container to share between API (because of primary keys, maybe some sensitive data, it depends).

Moreover if you want your embeddableId to work, request have to be build like in the example json. Proper fields have to be filled out. When requests arent build that way and they are just flat json without 'embedded id' you have to create some wrapper wich will fit the json format(this wrapper will be the requestbody class or List). Nextly you will have to convert wrapper to your db object with embedded id(created with a new keyword). 
And this is why i suggest you not to use the composite or embedded id. This is simple example where do you have just one table, but when it comes to use foreign keys and multicolumn primary keys, the tabels are getting more complicated and messy, you make searching over db harder and this is why i suggest you to use surrogate id's without embedding anything, it makes things harder and is just messy

Comment: i think that is an answer for you question or am i still missing something?